# How do I say "without (noun)" using なしに or なしで?

Tags: word-choice

I know how to say "without" when it comes to verbs using 〜ないで.  But I was wondering how to use "without" when it comes to nouns.  For example:

> I left without my wallet.

or

> I left without my glasses.

Sometimes I see なしに or なしで after a noun, and I wonder what the difference between them is and how to use them.  How do I say "without (noun)" using なしに or なしで?

Comment: Could you provide more context or some examples and explain where exactly lies your difficulty?

Comment: Please provide some example sentences using the two words in question.

Comment: You could add 抜き{ぬき} to the list...

Comment: Isn't なしく a typo of なく?

Comment: i'm sorry. i was wondering how to say...
"i left without......(object)..."
i know how to use without when is comes to verbs like: 
"なにも 買わないで, store に 行く."
i went to the store without buying anything. 

i was just curious how to use "without" when it comes to objects.
sometimes i see なしに or なしで i wonder whats the difference and how to use them

Comment: If you understand "なにも 買わないで then why can't you say "I did not buy..."? Perhaps you should summarise what your text book/teacher advises, where なしで, なしに, and なしく fit in and what is not clear?

Comment: My question is how to sat "without " when is comes to nouns or objects. 
For example: "I left without my wallet" 
                         "I Went without my glasses" etc.

Comment: @user5292 please use the edit button to add extra information to your question. If you make it clear enough it will be reopened!

Comment: I added the information from the comments thus far to the best of my ability.  (I've left out the example sentence for 〜ないで since it doesn't quite work, but you could perhaps ask a separate question about that.)

Answer (score 4):

なし isn't really used this way.  Just in terms of how the language works idiomatically, I've more often heard this expressed by using a different verb first:

- XX を忘れて出かけました。
  I forgot my XX and left. → I left without my XX.
- XX をテーブルに置いたまま出かけちゃった。
  I put XX on the table, and with it still there, I left → I left with XX still on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I've googled and found this article, which makes sense to me. http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/894749.html

Concrete examples to your asked usage of なしで or なしに could be

```
地図なしに、旅行はできない
地図なしで、旅行はできない
```

which both sounds to be proper Japanese (for me).  Their translation would be, as you might already knew, `Without map, I cannot travel.`

Their difference, I am still not very clear.  I assume they are generally the same.